# App with widget accesing to database

Tags: android, database, widget

I trying to make my widget get content form database, but its not working :/
And I dont really get it what's wrong

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {   
 private databaseHelper dbHelper;
 SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 @Override 
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)     { 
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT column01 FROM my_table WHERE column02=1", null);
                    cursor.moveToPosition(0);
                     String str0 = cursor.getString(0);
                     RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews( 
                    context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget); 
             updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, str0); 
             appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews); 
         } 
     }
```

Comment: you didn't write where is your problem. Pls define "its not working"... provide some logs from LogCat, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what part "isn't working", but you are passing the wrong value into `updateAppWidget`.  Replace this:

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);
```

with this:

```
for (int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++){
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], updateViews);
}
```

You are passing an array of `int`s, when you need to pass each array element individually.